# Cannot get my Android Phone (2.1) to be recognized by Eclipse in MacOSX 10.6

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, adb, android-2.1-eclair

I'm having trouble getting Eclipse as well as adb to recognize by device. I have followed the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), with no luck. I have turned on USB Debugging and connected my phone via the USB cable provided...
I have also turned it on and off, as well as reconnected the cable multiple times - as been suggested in other threads. I have also restarted the phone multiple times. The andriod phone says that USB Debugging is Connected in the status bar and MacOSX shows it's connected and you can browse the files available to browse using Finder.

I'm really stuck here, and I'm sure I've done just about everything....

Thanks in advance, it would be much appreciated if someone helped me solve this :)

This is the output when use 'adb devices' in the console:

```
List of devices attached
```

Not really that helpful...

***Relevant System Info:***

**Model Number**: Vodafone 845

**Firmware Version**: 2.1-update1

Comment: whats your device model.

Comment: @PadmaKumar Well, this might be the problem. It's a Vodafone 845 (A cheap knockoff of another phone most probably, re-branded with the Vodafone logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//This table provides a reference to the vendor IDs needed in order to add USB device support on Linux.
    [CompanyUSBVendorID](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

```
Acer    0502
ASUS    0B05
Dell    413C
Foxconn 0489
Garmin-Asus 091E
Google  18D1
HTC 0BB4
Huawei  12D1
K-Touch 24E3
KT Tech 2116
Kyocera 0482
Lenevo  17EF
LG  1004
Motorola    22B8
NEC 0409
Nook    2080
Nvidia  0955
OTGV    2257
Pantech 10A9
Pegatron    1D4D
Philips 0471
PMC-Sierra  04DA
Qualcomm    05C6
SK Telesys  1F53
Samsung 04E8
Sharp   04DD
Sony Ericsson   0FCE
Toshiba 0930
ZTE 19D2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I missed that. Looks like I'll have to go out and buy another phone :)